# How Java wrapper classes implements factory pattern?

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I was reading about the factory design pattern and saw some examples mentioned in articles that wrapper classes like Integer and Boolean use a `valueof` method which returns an object created by the factory equivalent to the value of the parameter passed.

When I check the code I see the below code. I am unable to understand how the factory pattern is implemented in a wrapper class.

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
         return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: `Integer.valueOf` is a factory method however it's implemented: it's a function you call to give you an object. That is the factory pattern.

Comment: I think it was rather about set of overloaded `valueOf` methods than about one specific

Comment: @khelwood, however `Integer` is `final`, so most of the concept goes out through the window. What remains is a method creating an object, kinda (because there is the cache, but as the object is immutable, it behaves like brand new, just it being immutable also takes away a bit from the excitement).

Comment: *How Java wrapper classes implements factory pattern?* - barely.

Answer (score 0):

It is the factory pattern that is implemented in the `Integer` class. While looking into it, you will notice it has 3 different implementations that **create** an `Integer` depending on the parameter type. The [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a **creational** pattern.

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i)

public static Integer valueOf(String s)

public static Integer valueOf(String s, int radix)
```

Also, in the case of the `Integer` class, another pattern is used, the [static constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods), recommended in the book [Effective Java](https://www.amazon.ca/Effective-Java-3rd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0134685997).